# Remove newspaper wordpress theme automatic post/page description

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta-tags, description-logic

I am using Newspaper theme for my [wordpress blogging website](https://emotionxpert.com) (https://emotionxpert.com) and using Rank Math SEO plugin. I usually use Rank Math to add my blog meta description but when I see the source code of any page, it shows two description, first is automatically generating by wordpress theme and second is that I writes using Rank Math. I want to remove automatic generated meta description.

I tried much, also use newspaper official documents but not found any solution.